# How do I start an activity when the user has reached their destination?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using the drop in UI for mapbox navigation in android and I want to start a new activity displaying information about a place once the user has navigated to it. How would I do that? Is there a handler to close the navigation view once done or do I have to rely on the user pressing the cancel button at the bottom of the navigation screen?

Comment: Well, you would need some thread or callback to detect when the destination is reached... What have you tried to find that event?

Comment: I looked at the api docs for Navigation Launcher and I didn't find any trigger events https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/navigation-sdk/navigation-ui/0.6.2/index.html. So I'm wondering if that means I can't use the UI SDK for my use case and instead have to use the Navigation one and make the UI myself.

Comment: You wan't the Navigation SDK, yes. You can use either Milestones or Route Progress https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/route-progress/

Comment: The MapBox UI doesn't need to handle starting new Activities - that's just a built in Android method.

Answer (score 1):

A callback once the UI has finished isn't currently supported in the `0.6.2` (or 6.3) release.  For `0.7.0` we have worked to convert `NavigationView` to an actual `View` which can be inflated in any `Activity` or `Fragment`.

An example of how to do this is in `NavigationActivity`: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/libandroid-navigation-ui/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/ui/v5/NavigationActivity.java

You'll see there is a callback that's triggered when the navigation session is cancelled / finished.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can detect whether the user has reached their destination or not. Either using the OnProgressChange and checking the `routeProgress.distanceRemaining()` is greater than 99%. You could also add a milestone to your navigation session and have it notify you when the sessions complete

Comment: I'm not seeing how I could do this if I'm passing an origin and destination to NavigationLauncher.startNavigation